# Back4App security permissions by the default selected as public

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

I found this setup on Back4App dashboard (Security tab in the class).

[image]

As you see Class Level Permissions view says that all Public checkers are selected.

Does it mean that anyone can access my class from the NET even without authentication?

Also I see that I can search through role, user or pointer. Which means this view only for adding some permission for selected items which I have not added yet.

But I am curious to know if this is some setting I need to adjust by myself and all classes are public open by default.

I know there are some articles about security set-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default, they are currently set as public, but I highly recommend you to set them according to your needs, in order to avoid that you'll not let any sensitive data as public or allow that data can be read/update by someone that shouldn't have access for it.

As you tagged Back4App, I'd like to share some security guides created from them, here they are:

- https://www.back4app.com/docs/security/parse-security
- https://blog.back4app.com/parse-server-security/

You can also check the Security session of the open-source documentation: http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#security

I hope these links might help you. :)